# "dotenv: error when sourcing '.env' file"?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, dotenv

Every time I `cd` a particular directory using either Terminal or iTerm2 (I'm running Macos 10.14.5, Node 12.13.0), I get the following error that seems to be complaining about an ´.env´ file provided to me by my team. They are not getting the error.

```
.env:22: parse error near '}'  
dotenv: error when sourcing '.env' file 
.env:22: parse error near '}'
```

Line 22, which seems to be causing the error is

`COOKIE_SETTINGS={"isSecure": false, "isSameSite": false, "isHttpOnly": true, "encoding": "base64json", "path": "/"}`

Any clue how I might remedy this? Thanks for any insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't store objects inside `.env` file.
The solution is to:
Stringify JSON object and save as env variable. Then parse and use it when you need your object.

Another solution is to write variables like this:

```
COOKIE_SETTINGS_IS_SECURE = false
COOKIE_SETTINGS_IS_SAME_SITE = false
...
```

Answer (score 1):

This seem error when parsing env.
I think env just support like string or number for this case.
Maybe you can use in **.env**

```
COOKIE_SETTINGS="{'isSecure': false, 'isSameSite': false, 'isHttpOnly': true, 'encoding': 'base64json', 'path': '/'}"
```

In JS just use **JSON.parse** to turn back to Object

```
cookieSettings= process.env.DB_HOST ? JSON.parse(process.env.DB_HOST) : null;
```